# Using backtrace_debug to determine caller class and caller method for the function. Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: php, oop

I have a parent class and a children class. In a parent class I define a function f() and want to print in it name of children class that extended parent class and name of children method that called this function. I do it like that.

```
abstract class ParentClass {

  public function f() {
       $backtrace = debug_backtrace();      
       echo "Class: " . $backtrace[1]['class']) . "\n";
       echo "Function: " . $backtrace[1]['function'];
  }

}

class ChildrenClass extends ParentClass {

   public function some_func() {
        $this->f();
   }
}


$o = new ChildrenClass;
$o->some_func();
```

And it correctly outputs me:

```
Class: ChildrenClass
Function: some_func
```

The question is: is my solution appropriate or there is a better way to achieve this?
I tried to use `__CLASS__` and `__FUNCTION__` but it always gives me a classname and function name of the parent class.

Answer (score -1):

If you print out the $backtrace var you might see it goes into a more classes

```
echo "Debug:<pre>".print_r($backtrace,true)."</pre><br />";
```

So calling

```
$backtrace[1]['class']
```

will work but you might make this dynamic. Something like:

```
// Loop, pseudo-code 
$i = 0;
$backtrace[$i]['class']
$i++;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also get the name of child class by http://php.net/get_called_class